# Bind to a veth interface

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, raw-sockets

Trying to bind my code to a veth interface . I need to create a RAW_SOCKET for this.

Creating my veth interface using

```
ip link add veth10 type veth peer veth10p
```

Can someone help me with the code for connecting to one end of the veth connection (i.e. veth10 in my example).

Answer (score 0):

You need to get interface index first - under linux you can use `struct ifreq` and `ioctl`. I have written my own ARP request which is not actually what you need but you can observe the code to understand working with interfaces (name -> index)

https://github.com/petrbel/pvu2/blob/master/arp-request/arp.c#L59

Hope it helped a little